# How to run Google now in backgroud?

Tags: google-now, voice-recognition, voice-command, google-voice-actions

*I don't know where to ask the question, so if you want to migrate it to SO or software recommendations please do so. If what I'm asking for requires programming, I can do that, if it requires root, I have a rooted s3 mini android version 4.2.2 and I can also pay for apps*

My current device is Samsung A5, not rooted, running android 5.0.2. I have tasker. I want to keep google now running in the background (not the launcher, the voice recognition system).

So it doesn't require me to say "ok google" for it to run. I want to say some word followed by a command and it runs the command automatically. Big plus if I can make it work on lock screen too.

Comment: I think "Okay Google" is required otherwise it would always try to search for whatever it hears. Voices in the back ground, Music in the background and etc. However, I know on my device, Nexus 6 running 5.1.1. In the Google Settings app. Under Search & Now > Voice > Ok Google Detection, You can set it to always listening and it works whether the phone screen is on or off. You might be able to use Tasker to change the "key" word that the app listens for.

Comment: @jer3my you solved 99.99999 of the problem, the rest is optional for testing,  thanks so much, really thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you out. =)